# Angular Delete method doesn't pass pre-flight request when calling .net web api

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have delete method on UsersController:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteUser(Guid id)
        {
            User user = await db.Users.FindAsync(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Users.Remove(user);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok();
        }
```

And I have enabled Cors by installing package, enabling cors in WebApiConfig and adding this in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

I use Angular on frontend and I have service where I have call for delete methods:

```
public delete = (route: string) => {
    return this.http.delete(this.createCompleteRoute(route, environment.urlAddress));
  }
```

When I make a call using this function the url is: `http://localhost:52474/api/Users/"some guid"` but the call fails saying it didn't pass pre-flight request. Do I need to add something else to my config?

Comment: Do you have correctly defined the DI for the DbContext? I've fallen in this problem many times because problems with DI.

Comment: dont think so because when I tried get all and get methods it worked ok :/

Comment: Okey, so I think maybe are something wrong with your http request from the client side. I see you define "content type" in the web.config but in your request you don't add any header. try add a header like this:
{
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
}

As a parameter of http.delete method.

Comment: tried adding it, still the same :/

Comment: Have you tried make the request with Postman for example? Just for reduce the reasons that can be causing the problem

Comment: yes, when I try same url with postman the response is 200 ok and user is deleted

Comment: Can you post what's the result of the function   `this.createCompleteRoute(route, environment.urlAddress)`

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the settings in web.config and added `[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]` on top of controller and now it works.

Comment: So the problem was the line <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />, maybe you didn't set header correctly from the client side because with this filter you're allowing any header.